# special character in az subscription name breaks search

Tags: azure

I've got an old azure subscription with an ampersand (&) in the name.
I can't switch to it with `az account set -s "Salt & Pepper"` and have been passing the subscription ID instead of the name. The usual escape methods produce the same result as the original name:

```
$ az account list
[
  {
    "id": "foo-000-0000",
    "isDefault": true,
    "name": "Salt & Pepper",
    "state": "Enabled",
    ... 
  }
]

$ az account set -s "Salt & Pepper"

CommandNotFoundError: 'Salt & Pepper' is misspelled or not recognized by the system.
Try this: 'az account list'
```

How can I form the -s argument such that it can recognize my cluster name?

Comment: Sounds like something you should report at the Azure CLI repo https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli

Comment: Where are you running the `az` command from?